# Insert image without extension in a HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

How to insert an image with no extension in a HTML5 canvas ?

I want to take an image existing on a page in a canvas I create in this same page in the goal to access to it pixel array.
It works with an image who has an extension like .png but it doesn't work with an image wich doesn't have an extension.
How can I do to fix my problem ?

EDIT :
in html, I have :

```
<img id="id1" src="/blabla/test.png" />
<img id="id2" src="/tmp/qsdqsd" />
```

I use this script :

```
jQuery('body').append('<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>');
var img = new Image();
img.src = jQuery("#id1").attr("src");
var context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
```

context.drawImage(img , 0, 0);

It works whith the first img but doesn't with the second.

Comment: If your image doesn't have an extension, how is the browser supposed to know what it is? I say you should add an extension to the image in your script.

Comment: @CeaneLamerez - The browser knows because the server tells it what type it is, or through the file's header.

Comment: I know exactly what you're talking about, however, I advise that when you're manipulating assets in JS, use the file extension, or else the browser won't be able to correctly reference the file.

Comment: @flow you need to be more descriptive with your question. Copying from another canvas on the same page is trival and doesn't require an extension, http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/LY9zF/

Comment: Its about an image generated from a server, if I want to open the image in a new tab, my browser offer to download it instead show the picture in the browser.